# WPF Bind command property from selected item in observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am using Listview having datasource as observablecollection`<empclass>`

My overall class structure is like

```
Class empclass
{ 
 command = new RelayCommand(myfunction, true);

 private int _abc;
 public int abc
  {
    get { return _abc;}
    set { _abc = value;
    onpropertychanged("abc")
   }

 private int _pqr;
 public int pqr
  {
    get { return _pqr;}
    set { _pqr = value;
    onpropertychanged("pqr")
  }



 public void myfunction()
 {
   messagebox.show((abc+pqr).Tostring());
 }
}
```

i have a separate button, where on click i want to invoke command of selected item to show addition of abc and pqr on respected values present in that object.

It would be great If you could help me with small code example.

Thanks
Ashpak

Comment: Could you share your xaml and viewmodel code ?

Comment: Please update the code with the actual code. The presented code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a `ListView` named `lv`:

```
<ListView Name="lv" ... </ListView>
```

Then you can bind to the `SelectedItem` of that `ListView` and use the item's `command` property.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=SelectedItem.command}">Button Text</Button>
```

Note that for this to work you have to have a `public property` command, e.g.:

```
Class empclass
{ 
    public RelayCommand command {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, I dont either. But it have no idea about the rest of the code and why this is done the way it is now. I'm just trying to help solve the current problem.

Comment: Agree. It's no big deal anyway. But I'm just wondering, How often do you need to use Elementname for binding in real life ? It's quite rare for me. Maybe it's because I dun usually do custom control  ?

Comment: It is quite nice for parent-child relations and for collections if you want to show additional data for the current element

Comment: Hi Domysee,
Thanks a lot for your help.
It worked well.

Actually i am putting command object inside class because i have list view with ItemTemplate having looks similar to  

http://screencast.com/t/kP7B7RugP

and on top of it i got buttons like delete, add reminder etc..using those buttons i want to perform actions on selected items.

Your trick is perfect for me..!!
I hope i am using correct approach, i am not very friendly with WPF.

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem. I could say that putting the command on the viewmodel and operating on the selected item is better, but then again, I have no idea how your architecture looks like. So its impossible for me to judge. Just do it the way you think is right for you at the moment, if its a bad approach you'll find out soon enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 1. XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="SoButtonBindingHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:soButtonBindingHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:SoButtonBindingHelpAttempt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <soButtonBindingHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soButtonBindingHelpAttempt:Empclass}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding abc, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding pqr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                                <Button    Grid.Column="2"  Command="{Binding Command}" Content="Press me!"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid></Window>
```

2. ViewModel code Model code:

```
    public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Empclass>(new List<Empclass>
        {
            new Empclass{abc=2, pqr = 3},
            new Empclass{abc=5, pqr = 7},
            new Empclass{abc=11, pqr = 13},
            new Empclass{abc=17, pqr = 19}
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Empclass> ObservableCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Empclass : BaseObservableObject
{
    private ICommand _command;
    private int _abc;
    private int _pqr;

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand(myfunction)); }
    }

    public int abc
    {
        get { return _abc; }
        set
        {
            _abc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("abc");
        }
    }


    public int pqr
    {
        get { return _pqr; }
        set
        {
            _pqr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("pqr");
        }
    }


    private void myfunction()
    {
        //add you command logic here
        var temp = pqr;
        pqr = abc;
        abc = temp;
    }
}
```

3. MVVM parts implementation:

```
    public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<T> _execute;
    readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public void RefreshCommand()
    {
        var cec = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (cec != null)
            cec(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null) return true;
        return _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : RelayCommand<object>
{
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
        : base(_ => execute(),
            _ => canExecute == null || canExecute())
    {

    }
}
```

4. Look like this:[image: looks like]

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help..really appreciate detailed explanation.

i do not want to put multiple buttons, i got only one button which is not part of listitem. and using it i want to invoke command from observable collection selected item.
I am not putting code here because it is some what big in size.

Comment: above accepted answer is what i was looking for.
Thanks again for your efforts IIan.